# Multiple values from ajax with undertermined number of value

Tags: php, ajax

**Context:**

I want to get multiple values from my database with ajax and php. I see previous post about this (like [How to get multiple responses from PHP file via AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104597/how-to-get-multiple-responses-from-php-file-via-ajax?rq=1) ) but all the time it seems the number of values is already known.

I have to return unknown number of values because i dont know how many roxs will be selected.

**Question:**

Are they tricks to get unknown number of values with ajax or should i put data in different arrays and then return them?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: -1 show your code, your effort

Comment: I dont know why you are under voting guys, i ask to people with more experience how they handle this problem. I dont want the anwser for doing this i want the best way to handle it. So no code will following. thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use JSON.

```
//PHP side
echo json_encode([$var1, $var2, $var3]);

//JS side
var array = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

Comment: How is that easier than JSON.parse(data); ? Also, you have a syntax error in .split().